# How to exclude multiple property keys from the Elasticsearch index when using GraphAware neo4j-to-elasticsearch integration

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, graphaware

In the [GraphAware neo4j-to-elasticsearch library](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-to-elasticsearch) I can see this property setting as a route to excluding certain Neo4j node properties from the Elasticsearch index:

```
com.graphaware.module.ES.node.property=key != 'age'
```

which works perfectly for a single property. But I can't see any documentation for how to specify multiple properties. I've made trial and error attempts with additional property names: comma separated; space separated and lots of other more left-field options but haven't had anything work yet.

Anyone have any experience in this area?

I'm using Neo4j 2.3.2 Enterprise and the appropriate GraphAware library versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting syntax comes from the Inclusion Policies :

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/tree/master/common#inclusion-policies

For excluding `age` and `name` you can do :

```
com.graphaware.module.ES.node.property=key != 'age' && key != 'name'
```

I will amend to readme to provide a link to the Inclusion policies documentation.

Comment: Christophe, thank you very much. That works very nicely!